# i had written logic that whether file exists or not. (reading file names in excel and checking whether file exists or not in another folder)

Tags: c#

In excel file file names will be there.The logic which i have written is it need to loop through all file names in excel and need to check whether file exists or not in another folder. the logic which i had written is doing properly but for the last row even the file exists it is displaying as file doesn't exists.could you please help

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.IO;
namespace ConsoleApp6
{
    class Class1
    {
        public void Data()
        {
            string file = @"D:\files\"; //this is the path for pdf file
            Application application = new Application();
            if (application == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("is not installed");
            }
            Workbook workbook = application.Workbooks.Open(@"D:\abc1.xlsx"); //this is the excel path
            _Worksheet excelSheet = workbook.Sheets[1];
            Range excelRange = excelSheet.UsedRange;
            int rows = excelRange.Rows.Count;
            int cols = excelRange.Columns.Count;
            //reading the rows and columns of excel file.
            for (int i = 1; i <= rows; i++)
            {
                //create new line
                Console.Write("\r\n");
                for (int j = 2; j < cols; j++)
                {
                    //write the console
                    if (excelRange.Cells[i, j] != null && excelRange.Cells[i, j].Value2 != null)
                    {
                        string xyz1 = excelRange.Cells[i, j].Value2;
                        string xyz = excelRange.Cells[i, j].Value2.ToString();
                        //File.Exists(file + xyz);
                        //below is the line of code where we are appending the file name with excel file.
                        if (!File.Exists(file + xyz))
                            Console.WriteLine("File does not exist.");
                        //Console.Write(excelRange.Cells[i, j].Value2.ToString() + "\t");
                    }
                }

            }
            //after reading, relaase the excel project
            application.Quit();
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(application);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are also traversing the columns but it is not clear if you want to check last column or not (your code doesn't). Did you check what is the value of xyz is?

Comment: the cell values in excel are the file names.actually iam taking the cell value of excel by looping the rows and it's respective column. and the last row column value it is taking and checking the file exists or not. here the issue is even if the file exists it is displaying as file not exists. iam getting the excel values in xyz.